# CSS coding style

Tags: css, coding-style

Are there any good CSS coding style/standards?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is a good one:

http://www.phpied.com/css-coding-conventions/

But the important thing is to pick something and stick with it for consistency.

Answer (score 11):

I agree with most of the points at Andrew Hare's link, but I *strongly* believe

```
.class-name {
    color: green;
}
```

is inferior to:

```
.class-name
{
    color: green;
}
```

on the grounds that:

```
.class-name, .class-name2 {
    color: green;
}
```

or:

```
.class-name, 
.class-name2 {
    color: green;
}
```

are considerably less obvious to grep or read than:

```
.class-name, 
.class-name2 
{
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: never thought about it that way. I think I might start using this convention

Comment: I don't know if that is "considerably less obvious" - this is just the OTBS war all over again.

Comment: Well the in-line grouping relies on you spotting the comma in the arbitrarily long selector string and the K+R format makes grepping that little bit harder since not all lines end uniformly - it's an easy thing to fix, why not go with clarity?

Answer (score 5):

There's no standard standard, as it were. There are most certainly plenty of in-house standards and conventions. And there are certainly known best practices.

I stick to the following:

- **Structure your CSS according to it's purpose**
  That may involve separating out CSS concerns into different files (layout.css, colors.css etc). This may just as well involve clearly dividing up a single CSS file into clear sections along the same lines.
- **Be as specific as possible**
  Selectors have differing weights. ID-based selectors are more specific than class-based selectors. Chained selectors (e.g. `body div#container div#content p`) are very specific indeed.

  Start out being as specific as you can, even if it appears you're being too specific. It's quite easy, later down the line, to merge together two very specific style definitions by removing one and making the other less specific.

  A style definition with loose specificity may target elements you did not intend in ways that are not immediately apparent or obvious. I think this is the most common cause of CSS frustrations ("Why on earth will this `div` not let me set a top margin?")
- **Always specify every single style you wish to apply for a given defintion**
  For example, if you want all your paragraphs to have pink text, set the text colour to pink and also set the margins/padding/background colour/font and so on.

  Don't rely on browser defaults to be suitably consistent. Certainly for the most commonly used elements the main browsers tend to use very similar if not identical default styling.

  If you set all the relevant styles yourself you know what the end result should be.
  If you only set those styles that are most immediately obvious, the end result will be (most likely) a combination of the browser defaults and your styles. This will eventually catch you out at some point. I think this is the second most common cause of CSS frustrations.
- **Use `id`s for styling unique elements**
  It's generally a good idea to apply an `id` attribute to any unique element that is going to be interacted with in any way. For CSS this will let you apply suitably specific styles more easily.
- **Use an `id` on a unique page**
  Pages that are significantly different in style and layout to the majority (homepage, search results, 404) should have an `id` on the `body` element. This gives you the specificity you need to ensure that your careful homepage styling doesn't get affected by styles you later apply to some internal content page.

Answer (score 3):

The main good coding style is to actually separate css files according to their goals.

See [Progressive Enhancement](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/progressiveenhancementwithcss).

That way, whatever coding convention you will choose, you will have consistent and manageable separate css files... easier to debug.

Answer (score 2):

**Pretty coding style VS site speed**

I've been working with pretty huge CSS files, and found out some pretty interesting things that I've never read about before.

**@import**

One thing is using @import. That's actually a bottleneck - by going away from using @import completely, the site got a lot more snappy.

**#every .style { in one line }**

When the browser reads a document, it reads line by line, so by switching from my pretty coding style to this, I accomplished 2 things;

1. A even more snappy site
2. Less scrolling, better overview. Why? Cause I first scroll down to find the style I'm going to work with, then it's all in the same line and it's not hard to scroll your eyes along the line to find what you're looking for.

Comment: I can't imagine in a modern browser that you would get that much of a performance benefit from putting your classes in a single line; can you give an example of how much of a performance gain you were seeing?  I would favor well formatted code over compact code, even for a modest performance gain.

Comment: Yeah, with everything in one line and no linewrapping the overall structure of ones design becomes much more obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Check [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) out. It's a template language for CSS that makes your source code DRY:er and mucho easy to read. Even if you're not using ruby you can use it for this task and automate the building of your css files from Sass source. And there are probably Sass implementations in other languages too.

Comment: New URL for [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/)

Answer (score 1):

When I code in CSS:

- In first part I write the class and id
- In last part I write the general element (p, font, etc) because the class and id have more importance for inheritance
- I write comment if I want a particular behaviour with IE or with MoSE Browser

You can see some example in [CSS Zen Garden](http://www.csszengarden.com)

Generally I insert the most important elements over the other: if there's

```
p.important{/*features of a class*/}

p {/*features of a general element */}
```

Reading the CSS file I know the format rules before about the most **particular** elements, after the rules about the most **general** elements.
It's an habit in programming Java.

Comment: I actually think this is exactly the inverse of how you should structure for the exact same reason: class and id having more specificity means tags will have more *effect* and are therefore more important to inheritance

Answer (score 1):

Just from experience I used to write quite long CSS style sheets. Now my style sheets typically are half a page.

So keep it simple(KISS), line based (greppable) and keep it compact (use font: instead of font-size etc etc.).

Also I highly recommend using [CSSlint](http://csslint.net) to check your code for fluff.

Comment: good points especially compactness

Comment: I also think that this is a good point. But it doesn't fit with @annakata 's answer regarding the Brace Style and is also against Jon Cram's opinion regarding _Always specify every single style you wish to apply for a given defintion_

Answer (score 1):

Put your css rules (ex: "color: red;") in alphabetical order and also put your selectors (ex: "div { color: red; }") in order they appear in your markup. Separate code for structure from skin.

Answer (score 1):

I will strongly recommend looking at Less: http://lesscss.org

While not really a standard, it has been gaining a lot of momentum recently. Less is css extension that runs in the browser bringing variables and functions into the language and therefore allowing templating.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably loads.  At our work we use the following:

```
/* =div a comment about my div */
div#mydiv {
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

The =div allows us to search against all div elements by using the search functionality.  There's loads more though, I've used many different variations of this in the past.

Comment: what kind of comments do you use for css ?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what others said, remember that the C stands for 'Cascading', i.e. subelements inherit from top level elements. Sound simple and straight away. But I have often seen CSS files that contain redundant declarations, e.g. for font styles. This makes a CSS more complex and hard to maintain.

So before you add something to your CSS make sure that it is not redundant, i.e. check parent elements and remove redundant declarations from children.

Given this you should organize your CSS in a way so that high level elements (like declarations for the body class) are mentioned first and more specialized elements last.

Answer (score 0):

This might also be helpful, a few tips to keep your CSS styles DRY - as in "Don't Repeat Yourself" [link text](http://reinholdweber.com/?p=46)